# Fetching records from SQLite with date field saved as text in android

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Hiii Freinds

I have an serious issue in android.I am using SQlite as my DB. In my application i am storing date as text field as sqlite don't have date datatype.In the report section i am taking from and to date from user fetching records from sqlite as below,

```
select * from Table2 where TDate >= '2013-1-1' and TDate <='2013-3-1'
```

The problem is that above query runs correct ,but when I use date with month higher than 10 eg.'2013-10-1' or '2013-11-1' or '2013-12-1' it was not fetching any records please help

Thankx In adv.

Answer (score 0):

You must use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) such as `yyyy-mm-dd` so that the string comparison come out right.
(In a string, `1` < `9`, therefore `10` < `9`.)

Comment: Yaa but I am using correct date format i.e yyyy-mm-dd thats why its fetching records for me up to 9 months

Comment: You are not; your month/date fields do not have two digits.